# What happens with an accidental excess contribution to an ISA?

Tags: united-kingdom, investing, isa, excess-contribution, mistakes

I handle joint internet banking for myself and my husband.  Our online account happens to have been created using my husband's personal details.

While logged in under this account (as usual) I attempted to open an ISA in my name.  Despite entering all my personal details, the ISA was nonetheless created in my husband's name.

Before realizing this, I deposited the maximum yearly amount.  Because my husband already has a Stocks & Shares ISA in his name (to which we contribute a small amount each month), he has now effectively over-contributed for this year.

What happens now?

Comment: You will only get relief for £15k(combined). What is stopping you from withdrawing the amount and putting it in your name ?

Comment: @DumbCoder that not how ISA's work take it out you lose it

Comment: @Pepone - Yes I know that. My assumption was they might have different banks for their stocks and shares ISA and cash ISA.

Comment: @DumbCoder I imagine there's a risk that, since some of the cash contribution apparently happened before the S&S contributions, that if HMRC got wind of it they might declare that some of the S&S contributions were invalid.  If that happens, and the OP has already withdrawn valid cash contributions, a portion of the allowance may well be wasted.

Answer (score 3):

You should speak to HMRC about the correct way to unpick this.

The [ISA helpline number](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/hm-revenue-customs/contact/individual-savings-accounts-isa-enquiries) is 0300 200 3312.